# I am getting Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am new to flutter and making an app with null safety but getting this error!
I think the error is caused by misc.dart specifically while declaring the firestore reference.
I tried dart migrate as well but it didn't help.
I got this error when I am running my simple flutter App. I could not figure out why this error occurred.

I am pasting the code below:
Thankyou

Stack Traces:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building DashboardPage(dirty, dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<DocumentSnapshot<Misc>?>, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#55bd8],
_InheritedTheme], state: _DashboardPageState#de55a):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  DashboardPage
  DashboardPage:file:///Users/inductor/Desktop/vitcc_electrical_issues-main/lib/main.dart:42:22

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MiscSnapshotExtension.misc
```

misc.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'misc.freezed.dart';

typedef MiscSnapshot = DocumentSnapshot<Misc>;

@freezed
class Misc with _$Misc {
  const Misc._();

  const factory Misc._create({
    required List<String> locationBlocks,
    required int activeIssuesCount,
    required int resolvedIssuesCount,
  }) = _Misc;

  static const _LocationBlocksKey = 'location-blocks';
  static const _ActiveIssuesCountKey = 'active-issues-count';
  static const _ResolvedIssuesCountKey = 'resolved-issues-count';

  static final _ref =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('misc').withConverter<Misc>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, options) {
      final data = snapshot.data()!;

      return Misc._create(
          locationBlocks: data[_LocationBlocksKey].cast<String>(),
          activeIssuesCount: data[_ActiveIssuesCountKey],
          resolvedIssuesCount: data[_ResolvedIssuesCountKey]);
    },
    toFirestore: (value, options) {
      return {
        _LocationBlocksKey: value.locationBlocks,
      };
    },
  ).doc('default');

  static get ref => _ref;

  static Stream<MiscSnapshot> get watch => _ref.snapshots();

  static Future<MiscSnapshot> get read => _ref.get();

  static Future<void> informIssueCreated() async {
    await _ref.update({
      _ActiveIssuesCountKey: FieldValue.increment(1),
    });
  }

  static Future<void> informIssueResolved() async {
    await _ref.update({
      _ActiveIssuesCountKey: FieldValue.increment(-1),
      _ResolvedIssuesCountKey: FieldValue.increment(1),
    });
  }

  static Future<void> informActiveIssuePurged() async {
    await _ref.update({
      _ActiveIssuesCountKey: FieldValue.increment(-1),
    });
  }

  static Future<void> updateActiveIssuesCount(int value) async {
    assert(value >= 0, 'bad argument: cannot write negative value');

    if (value < 0) {
      return;
    }

    await _ref.update({_ActiveIssuesCountKey: value});
  }
}

extension MiscSnapshotExtension on MiscSnapshot {
  Misc get misc => this.data()!;
}
```

Dashboard.dart

```
class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();

  static _DashboardPageState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_DashboardPageState>()!;
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  bool _raiseNewIssueFormIsShown = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    final misc = Provider.of<MiscSnapshot>(context).misc;

    final userSnapshot = Provider.of<UserSnapshot>(context);
    final user = userSnapshot.user;

    NetworkImage? userPhoto;

    final photoUrl = Provider.of<User>(context).photoURL;

    if (photoUrl != null) {
      userPhoto = NetworkImage(photoUrl);
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: FadeInLeft(
          preferences: const AnimationPreferences(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          ),
          child: Text(
            _raiseNewIssueFormIsShown
                ? 'Raise an issue'
                : ElectricalIssueTrackerApp.appName,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: () => showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => MiscellaneousDialog(userSnapshot),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: PhysicalModel(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 3,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: theme.primaryColor,
                  child: Text(
                    ('${user.name}${user.email}-'[0]).toUpperCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    ),
                  ),
                  foregroundImage: userPhoto,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: CupertinoScrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Wrap(
            spacing: 10,
            runSpacing: 30,
            children: [
              // The analytics widget
              ActiveAndResolvedIssueCounters(misc: misc),

              // View all active issues if user has permission
              if (user.scope.canViewActiveIssues) ActiveIssuesSection(),

              if (user.scope.canViewResolvedIssues)
                buildResolvedIssuesButton(misc, userSnapshot),

              // Raise an issue section
              if (user.scope.canCreateIssue) RaiseAnIssueSection(),

              // All issues raised by the user.
              MyIssuesSection(),

              // Footer
              SizedBox(height: 30),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showRaiseNewIssueForm(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() => _raiseNewIssueFormIsShown = true);

    await Scaffold.of(context)
        .showBottomSheet((_) => RaiseNewIssueBottomSheet())
        .closed;

    setState(() => _raiseNewIssueFormIsShown = false);
  }

  Widget buildResolvedIssuesButton(Misc misc, UserSnapshot userSnapshot) {
    return Center(
      child: OutlinedButton(
        child: Text('View already resolved issues'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return MultiProvider(
                providers: [
                  Provider.value(value: userSnapshot),
                  Provider.value(value: misc),
                ],
                child: ResolvedIssuesPage(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Null check is `!` so it probably means one of your variables value where you are using null check returns `null` so check those variables and maybe use `if(data != null) {...} else {...}`.